# Is truth a defense against defamation laws in Indonesia?

Tags: defamation, indonesia

If so how?

I read 310 KUHP laws in Indonesia and it says that public interest is a defense. It doesn't list truth as defense.

Some says that if we have evidences, that is defense. What kind of evidences are good enough defenses?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relying on [this version](http://www.wipo.int/edocs/lexdocs/laws/en/id/id039en.pdf), proof of truth is only allowed in order to establish a "public interest" defense or for a "necessary defense"; but also "if an official is charged with the commission of an act in the exercise of his office". Good luck with "necessary defense". It is not a defense to say "But what I said is true". However, if the defamed person has been convicted in court of said act (the defamatory statement) then there can be no punishment.

Comment: are you an indonesian lawyer?

Comment: Mercy sakes no, not even a murkan lawyer.

Comment: Any Indonesian lawyer here?